# Blurry SVG images

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I'm having a really hard time figuring out why my SVG images are blurry? I tried using different size images based off screen size(small, medium, large). Since I couldn't get that working I read that SVG is your best bet since it maximizes, minimizes on it's own. However, my client still feels the images are blurry. They are blurry in desktop and mobile.  I can't seem to figure out why. Is it possible because they are inside `<div>`s? I'm using bootstrap for my entire project. I am importing them by `<img src>` I have looked over the SVG images and made sure they are rounded to the nearest whole number. Example, the logo svg is all whole numbers and they are all the same size. If anyone can let me know I would appreciate it.

Logo image dimensions

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="212px" height="69px" viewBox="0 0 212 69" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" ><rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="0" y="0" width="212" height="69" style="fill:none;stroke:none;"/><image x="0" y="0" width="212" height="69" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/></svg>
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <!--<div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap">-->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#index.html"><b>Wanzeru</b></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#content2"><b>Feature</b></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#content3"><b>Integrating</b></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#content4"><b>Pricing</b></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#content6"><b>About</b></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand{

    margin-bottom: -10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right: 6rem;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-right: .7rem;
    font-size: 15px;


}
```

[image]

Comment: can you post a snippet with some minimal version of your SVG's?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMullany I have gone ahead and added my SVG code for the logo image. Per my understanding, you can just src the SVG image in your html doc, aside from that I have not implemented anything else. I have also added a screen shot of the logo itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use vectors, not pixel/raster/bitmap images. Your logo image is a SVG, but it contains a an embedded (base64 encoded) pixel image:

`<image x="0" y="0" width="212" height="69" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,xyz">`

That's why it gets blurred when scaling. Make sure that you export your images as true vector graphics.

Google for the differences between vectors and pixels for a thorough explanation. Vectors describe images by geometric patterns in a coordinate systems - so that scaling the image doesn't have any influence on quality.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Can you recommend a software that easily saves an image as a vector image?

Comment: Well, it's about creating an image as a vector image - then saving the image as a vector image. StackOverflow is not the right place for software recommendations though. Any vector programm will do. Popular choices are Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape or Affinity Designer. My personal favourite being the latter.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I received the images per the graphic artist. It's safe to assume to ask her to supply me with the vector images as I'm just a web developer?

Comment: @Alexandra Sorry for the extremely late reply. I will answer as a formality, nonetheless  Yes, the graphic artist should be able to supply you with the vector version.